# Angular js how can I filter data using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

In my Html I displayed two times "OUI" I think because I have two default installations (delestage, default command') how can I filter them one by one using ng-class and ng-repeat.

```
 <div  ng-repeat="value in installationsHelper" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
                    <div ng-repeat="value1 in value.InstallationDefautsTypes.value | filter :  'D'">{{value.InstallationDefautsTypes.value}}
                        <span ng-class="value1 ? 'mDefault' : 'mDanger'">
                            OUI
                        </span>

    <script>
     angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {      
 $scope.installationsStates = [
                {
                    Installations: {
                        id: 1
                    },
                    InstallationsDefautsTypes : {
                       Delestage:
                     {
                        name: "Delestage", 
                        value : false, 
                        id: 1}
                     defaut command:
                        {
                        name: "Delestage", 
                        value : false, 
                        id: 1
                     }
                      }
                    },
                    defaultsInstallations: {
                        0:"defaut",
                        1:"Delestage"
                    }
                },
                {
                    Installations: {
                        id: 2
                    },
                    InstallationsDefautsTypes : {
                     Delestage:{
                        name: "Delestage", 
                        value : false, 
                        id: 1
                      }

        });
```

Comment: Do you need filter data or color text by a boolean?

Comment: Heloo Ans have you an idea please

Comment: i need to filter  color text  by boolean and i have to defaults

Comment: Make your question more clear that what you want to show or what do you mean by filter?

Answer (score 4):

[By documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression

If you want change color of the text by a boolean you can use `ng-class` in this way:

```
<any class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </any>
```

in your case:

```
<span ng-class = "ng-class="value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.value ? 'red' : 'black'">
                OUI
            </span>
```

where `red` or `black` have to be **defined css class**.

Indeed for filtering data you have two different method:

1. Inside the html
2. In a function inside controllers

[By documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

```
{{ expression [| filter_name[:parameter_value] ... ] }}
```

In this case thanks to the "pipe" you can add a filter in your code.

E.g.
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithA">
    {{ friend }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('startsWithA', function () {
  return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (/a/i.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

You can also filter your data on controller (you must add to the scope a new filtered list) and then add inside `ng-repeat` your filtered list.

Comment: How you can do that inside html please

Comment: the filter or the ng-class?

Comment: @hakim don't edit my answer with your code, at most add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change color dynamically, you can use ngStye.

```
 <span [ngStyle]="{'color': value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.value ? 'red' : 'black'}"> 
       OUI
  </span>
```

i used this :

```
<div  ng-repeat="value in installationsHelper" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">

                        <span ng-class="value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.value ? 'mDefault' : 'mDanger'">
                            OUI
                        </span>

                </div>
```

Comment: i changed the Json  you can see now please

Comment: i want to filter InstallationsDefautsTypes , how i can filter a installationsDefautsTypes please

Comment: be careful, this code it could be works on angular2+ not in angularjs.

Comment: yes  but how i can filter the installationsDefautsTypes can you help me please

Comment: are you able to create a function on a controller?

Comment: i dont know how i can do that can you help me please to create a function

Comment: @hakim read here https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: can you help me hakim please

Comment: how i can do that in my situation please

Comment: @hakim in my reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/51498369/4149078
if you read well, you can find the `ng-class` example and the filter example (really easy to apply), please focus on understand the behavior of that code.

Comment: can you see my html code please carmelog i added a codecan you see them please